# Как установить php7 для Nginx, Magento 2?

Tags: nginx, magento

У меня есть запрос на php7 установки для Apache `sudo apt-get install -y php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-common php7.0-gd php7.0-mysql php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-curl php7.0-intl php7.0-xsl php7.0-mbstring php7.0-zip php7.0-bcmath php7.0-iconv`
Как мне правильно изменить команду, чтобы php7 с модулями работали на Nginx? Правильно ли я понимаю, что некоторые модули не понадобятся и имеют отношение к mod_php/mod_python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`libapache2-mod-php7.0` - этот модуль вам не нужен. Помимо перечисленного, вам так же нужно поставить `php7.0-fpm`.

Comment: А php7.0 должно остаться?

Comment: @SergeyEremin: не обязательно. `php7.0` - это метапакет (https://packages.debian.org/sid/php7.0) - т. е. пакет, установка которого приводит к установке нескольких других пакетов. Такие пакеты удобны что бы не ставить кучу модулей или часто используемых вместе пакетов по отдельности, а поставить их все сразу. Но т. к. вы и так перечисляете список необходимых вам модулей - можете и не указывать `php7.0`